# newline in powershell not show in notepad

Tags: powershell

if I open the test.txt with notepad, it's a single line, no newlines between two "test". but if I open it with vim or ultraedit, I could see the newlines. what's the reason?

```
Set-Content .\test.txt "test`n`ntest"
```

update:

```
"test" | Out-File .\test.txt -Encoding ascii -Append
```

will append a newline that could be shown

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use Windows line endings, rather than Unix ones:

```
Set-Content .\test.txt "test`r`ntest"
```

uses CRLF rather than your LFLF (CR = carriage return `` `r ``, LF = linefeed `` `n `` )

Notepad uses Windows line endings. Vim understands LF just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then you have a text file that has Unix newlines, instead of DOS carriage returns/line feeds.

Go into "hex edit" mode in UltraEdit and see if the end-of-line character is "0D0A" (carriage return/line feed), or just "0d" (newline).