# Controlling Line Breaks During Transcript in Powershell -maybe notepad

Tags: powershell

The following code produces the following one line entry in my text file egg.txt when opened with notepad - however notepad++ can recognise line breaks:

Script:

```
Start-Transcript egg.txt
Get-ChildItem -file | Copy-Item -Destination "c:\egg" -Verbose
Stop-Transcript
```

Outuput - notepad:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\.gitconfig Destination: C:\egg".VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\.zip Destination: C:\egg".VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\egg.txt Destination: C:\egg".
```

Outuput - notepad++:

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\.gitconfig Destination: C:\egg".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\.zip Destination: C:\egg".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Users\Craig\egg.txt Destination: C:\egg".
```

I guess I could do something along the lines of

```
  get-content | "string manipulate `n,`r`n" | set-content
```

at the end of the script (which may give me too many lines) or simply open the file with something other than notepad?

Are there some settings on start-transcript I could set?

Comment: This is an issue with CR,LF having applied the show all character button in notepad++ this is clear.

Comment: [This question is related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13283191/newline-in-powershell-not-show-in-notepad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Start-Transcript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) cmdlet is not really seen as a **logging** mechanism but more as a simple capture of the command executed, from which you can copy/paste excerpts of the script to play them back.

You could to something like this to generate a log file with proper CR/LF for notepad.

```
Start-Transcript egg.txt
Get-ChildItem -file | Copy-Item -Destination "c:\egg" -Verbose
Stop-Transcript

$log = Get-Content egg.txt
$log > Log.txt
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

Comment: Thanks.  What is a more recommended logging option?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for people who come across this as I did, try sending the transcript to a .log file. .log honors these line breaks. I recommend downloading trace32.exe to view these logs, you'll like the way it looks - I guarantee it.